# Modular arithmetic modulo $10^{2011}.$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there a natural number $n$ such that $3^{n} \equiv 7\ (\text {mod}\ 10^{2011})$

I can't come up with an idea how to solve it...

Comment: Look up [Hensel's lifting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma)

Comment: Look at it modulo eight.

Comment: I will gladly explain how I came up with that. But before I do, I want to recommend you to study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). This looks like a contest training problem. Why don't you give the source? That is one of the alternative ways of providing the kind of context we think all the questions should have.

Comment: Ok. A hint as to how I came up with the solution. There are powers of $3$ with the last two digits $07$. Namely $3^{15}$ and every twentieth ever after. But, writing their three last digits down (I didn't write down the whole things :-), you will spot something about the third last digit..

Comment: Thank you very much! I will read the guide! This is not a separate problem from a competition. I was solving modular arithmetic related to the last k digits of a number and came up with a problem which I transformed into this. Thank you again!

Comment: For $\ell\ge4$ powers of $3$ have $2^{\ell-2}\cdot5^{\ell-1}$ distinct remainders modulo $10^\ell$. That is one eighth of the remainders coprime to $10$.

Answer (score 3):

Simply to get this out of the unanswered queue. No. the original congruence can be rewritten as $$10^{2011}y+7=3^n$$ which works for any divisor of $10^{2011}$ 8 is such a divisor. The problem is no power of 3, is 7 mod 8. It therefore fails to be true.